# How to call Base Class's __init__ method from the child class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, constructor

If I have a python class as:

```
class BaseClass(object):
#code and the init function of the base class
```

And then I define a child class such as:

```
class ChildClass(BaseClass):
#here I want to call the init function of the base class
```

If the init function of the base class takes some arguments that I am taking them as arguments of the child class's init function, how do I pass these arguments to the base class?

The code that I have written is:

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"

    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
        self.battery_type=battery_type
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your format is wrong, is that a copy-and-paste problem? Python will bark on wrong format.

Comment: @Mingyu format is wrong? You mean indentation or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Yea.. I mean indentation.  Please look at my answer below.

Comment: don't use derived class name do this in python 3 (pseudocode): `super().__init__(args...)`

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You could use `super(ChildClass, self).__init__()`

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Your indentation is incorrect, here's the modified code:

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"

    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
        self.battery_type=battery_type
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)

car = ElectricCar('battery', 'ford', 'golden', 10)
print car.__dict__
```

Here's the output:

```
{'color': 'golden', 'mpg': 10, 'model': 'ford', 'battery_type': 'battery'}
```

Comment: If you pass `BaseClass` to `super`, it'll skip over `BaseClass` and call `object.__init__`, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Meanwhile, the only thing wrong with the OP's code is his indentation, explaining `super` (even if you explained it correctly, which you didn't) doesn't help, especially given that he already used it exactly the same way; in fact, it's character-for-character identical.

Comment: Thanks, @abarnert.  Initially, he did not post his  code and the question he asked is the one in the title.

Comment: Your answer is the most highly voted. You should really reference how to not use the derived class name by doing `super().__init__(args)`

Comment: @CharlieParker can you please expand? What should we _not_ do?

Answer (score 90):

As Mingyu pointed out, there is a problem in formatting. Other than that, I would strongly recommend **not using the Derived class's name** while calling `super()` since it makes your code inflexible (code maintenance and inheritance issues). In Python 3, Use `super().__init__` instead. Here is the code after incorporating these changes :

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"

    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

class ElectricCar(Car):

    def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
        self.battery_type=battery_type
        super().__init__(model, color, mpg)
```

Thanks to Erwin Mayer for pointing out the issue in using `__class__` with super()

Comment: Can you give any explanation for the recommendation 'not to use the Derived class's name'?

Comment: @jwg I updated the answer to explain why __class__ is a better choice.

Comment: @CraigFinch it doesn't seem to be a good idea at all to use self.__class__. In Python 3 you can simply use super().__init__

Comment: Yet another reason Py3 is superior to Py2.  (As someone who came to python after 3.4 came out)

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Python 3, it is recommended to simply call super() without any argument:

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"

    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
        self.battery_type=battery_type
        super().__init__(model, color, mpg)

car = ElectricCar('battery', 'ford', 'golden', 10)
print car.__dict__
```

Do not call super with **class** as it may lead to infinite recursion exceptions as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19776143/541420).

Comment: Just curious why all the answers in this question are setting self.battery_type before calling the super init method. Isn't it considered better practice to call super init before modifying anything in the object, so the base class is fully initialized first? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @mojoken Most likely because it was that way in the OP's question. I would agree that the reverse is usually better.

Answer (score 15):

You can call  the super class's constructor like this

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        print "parent", number

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(5)

b = B()
```

**NOTE:**

This will work only when the parent class inherits `object`

Comment: don't use derived class name do this in python 3 (pseudocode): super().__init__(args...)