# how to user super() in python class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I'm trying to implement `super()` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205916/how-to-call-base-classs-init-method-from-the-child-class) SO answer.

I have the following class:

```
class Collection():
    """returns a collection curser from mongodb"""  
    def __init__(self, db, collection_name):
        self.db = db
        self.collection_name = collection_name

        if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'client'):
            self.__class__.client = MongoClient()

        self.data_base = getattr(self.client, self.db)
        self.collection = getattr(self.data_base, self.collection_name)
```

and the following subclass:

```
class User(Collection):
    def __init__(self, db, collection_name):
        super(User, self).__init__(db, collection_name)
```

Calling the `Collection` class works fine:

```
agents = Collection('hkpr_restore','agents')
```

Calling the subclass:

```
user = User('hkpr_restore','agents')
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    user = User('hkpr_restore','agents')
  File "filepath/user.py", line 35, in __init__
    super(User, self).__init__(db, collection_name)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to do `Collection.client = ...` instead of `self.__class__.client = ...`, so that every subclass shares the same client and you use fewer connections. You may also use a global name instead of a class attribute.

Comment: If you're using Python 2 you should add a Python 2 tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit Collection from object like `Collection(object)` to create a new style class. This way, super will work (it only works with new style classes).

Comment: FWIW, all classes in Python 3 are new-style, so explicitly inheriting from `object` isn't need in Python 3. OTOH, writing `object` in Python 3 it doesn't hurt, and I guess it's nice to write code that performs properly on both Py 2 & Py 3, where practical.