# Python: How to call super() from instance object of the derived class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I want to call the super method from B of an instance object of the derived class in the following fashion:

```
class B:
    pass

class A(B):
    pass

a_object = A()
a_object.super().__init__()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'super'
```

Is there a way I can call super method in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already found the answer, you know you could use `super(ChildClass, self).__init__()`. I would like to explain how it works using a simple example. In the below piece of code, I have called `__init__` of BaseClass in the `__init__` of ChildClass.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #Calling __init__ of BaseClass
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

For example:

```
#Here is simple a Car class
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"

    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

#Inherit the BaseClass here
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
        self.battery_type=battery_type
        #calling the __init__ of class "Car"
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)

#Instantiating object of ChildClass
car = ElectricCar('battery', 'ford', 'golden', 10)
print(car.__dict__)
```

Here's the output:

```
{'color': 'golden', 'mpg': 10, 'model': 'ford', 'battery_type': 'battery'}
```

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205916/how-to-call-base-classs-init-method-from-the-child-class) to the question from which my explanation is inspired. Hope it helps someone understand the concept better :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a way using:

```
super(A, a_object).__init__()
```