# I don't understand the order of methods in python

Tags: python

I don't understand why the code uses the print_me method from Class D, and not the method in class A.

I did some testing using print-statements and can see that it reads the print_me-method of class D before initialising class A, but I don't understand why it doesn't do the same for class A.

```
class A:
    name = "Alfa"

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        foo = 100
        self.print_me()

    def print_me(self):
        print(self.name, self.foo)

class B(A):
    name = "Beta"

    def __init__(self, bar = 40):
        self.bar = bar
        print(self.name, bar)

class C:
    name = "Charlie"

class D(A, C):
    name = "Delta"

    def __init__(self, val):
        A.__init__(self, val)

    def print_me(self):
        print(self.name, "says", self.foo)

d = D(60)
```

The output is: Delta says 60

I thought it would be: Delta 60

Comment: Because the lookup starts from the "lowest" class. I'm pretty sure this behavior is the same in any other major OO language. Try to do `print(D.mro())`

Comment: So when it looks for the print_me method, it starts looking in class D cause that is the lowest class? And because it finds one, it's okay with it and uses that?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Loop up `method resolution order`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Base Class's \_\_init\_\_ method from the child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205916/how-to-call-base-classs-init-method-from-the-child-class)

Answer (score 3):

Because the `self` you are passing to the `__init__` of `A` is still an instance of `D`, not `A`. And the function `A.__init__` is calling `self.print_me`, which belongs to `D`.

If you do `a = A(); a.print_me()` you'd get what you expect.

Important note: The `__init__` method in python *is not* the actual constructor, it is just a method that is automatically called *after* the actual construction of the object. However, when you call it yourself, it works just like any other method.

Comment: This answer could use an explanation (or a link to an answer that explains) the  concept of MRO. If `D.print_me` will be removed then `A.print_me` will be called. Similarly, if `A.print_me` will be removed then `D.print_me` will be called.