# How to declare Class based on 'object'

Tags: python, c

I'm writing a Python class in C. In python code I use this as base class for other classes written in Python.

I need to call based class `__init__` function.
To do this I need to declare class base on object referring to this article [How to call Base Class's __init__ method from the child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205916/how-to-call-base-classs-init-method-from-the-child-class)

How to do this with `PyClass_New`?
I call it like this:

```
PyObject *moduleDict = PyModule_GetDict(ricc_module);
PyObject *classDict = PyDict_New(  );
PyObject *className = PyString_FromString("Device");
PyObject *fooClass = PyClass_New(NULL, classDict, className);
```

Comment: @Hulk It's C, probably writing a native C module for Python.

Comment: I have C project and making base Python class in C.In python code I use this base class fo other classes written in Python.

Comment: @DmitryChikov Ok, I've edited your question to include this information.