# How to solve AttributeError: type object 'LibraryItem' has no attribute 'Book_Title'?

Tags: python, class, subclass, base-class

Error occurs after running this piece of code. It says "AttributeError: type object 'LibraryItem' has no attribute 'Book_Title". Can an attribute defined in base class be accessed from derived class such as accessing it from a method?

```
import datetime

class LibraryItem:
    def __init__(self,t,a,i):
        self.__Title = t
        self.__Author = a
        self.__ItemID = i
        self.__OnLoan = False
        self.__DuteDate = datetime.date.today()

    def SetOnLoan(self,o):
        self.__OnLoan = o
    def SetDueDate(self,d):
        self.__DueDate = d

class Book(LibraryItem):
    def __init__(self,t,a,i):
        LibraryItem.__init__(self,t,a,i)
        self.__RequestedBy = 'people'

    def SetRequestedBy(self,r):
        self.__RequestedBy = r

    def GetRequestedBy(self):
        return self.__RequestedBy

    def PrintDetails(self):
        print(LibraryItem.__Title)

ThisBook = Book('Python','Tom','123')
ThisBook.PrintDetails()
```

Answer (score 1):

There're 2 points here:

1. initialization of a base class (LibraryItem) in `__init__` of `Book`, which should be done sligthly differently I believe (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205916/how-to-call-base-classs-init-method-from-the-child-class) for details)
2. the privacy of class attributes, which is achieved by different number of underscores (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name) for details). Basically two undescores hide the attribute.

The code

```
import datetime

class LibraryItem:
    def __init__(self,t,a,i):
        self.__Title = t
        self.__Author = a
        self.__ItemID = i
        self.__OnLoan = False
        self.__DuteDate = datetime.date.today()

    def SetOnLoan(self,o):
        self.__OnLoan = o
    def SetDueDate(self,d):
        self.__DueDate = d
    
    def GetTitle(self):
        return self.__Title

class Book(LibraryItem):
    def __init__(self,t,a,i):
        super(Book, self).__init__(t,a,i)
        self.__RequestedBy = 'people'

    def SetRequestedBy(self,r):
        self.__RequestedBy = r

    def GetRequestedBy(self):
        return self.__RequestedBy

    def PrintDetails(self):
        print(self.GetTitle())

ThisBook = Book('Python','Tom','123')
ThisBook.PrintDetails()
```

Produces output:

```
Python
```

Comment: Your answer works, but you've changed access mode from private to protected here.

Comment: Changed the code to use a separate getter instead.